# How can i group rows on sql base on condition

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, metabase

I am using redshift sql and would like to group users who has overlapping voucher period into a single row instead (showing the minimum start date and max end date)

For E.g if i have these records,

[image]

I would like to achieve this result using redshift

[image]

Explanation is tat since row 1 and row 2 has overlapping dates, I would like to just combine them together and get the min(Start_date) and max(End_Date)

I do not really know where to start. Tried using row_number to partition them but does not seem to work well. This is what I tried.

```
select 
    id, 
    start_date, 
    end_date, 
    lag(end_date, 1) over (partition by id order by start_date) as prev_end_date,
    row_number() over (partition by id, (case when prev_end_date >= start_date then 1 else 0) order by start_date) as rn
from users
```

Are there any suggestions out there? Thank you kind sirs.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Those are two very different database products

Comment: oh im sorry, redshift. Editted the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Because the dates are arbitrary, let me suggest the following approach:

- Use a cumulative max to get the maximum end_date before the current date.
- Use logic to determine when there is no overall (i.e. a new period starts).
- A cumulative sum of the starts provides an identifier for the group.
- Then aggregate.

As SQL:

```
select id, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select u.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date >= start_date then 0 else 1
                 end) over (partition by id
                            order by start_date, voucher_code
                            rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                           ) as grp
      from (select u.*,
                   max(end_date) over (partition by id
                                       order by start_date, voucher_code
                                       rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                      ) as prev_end_date                            
            from users u
           ) u
      ) u
group by id, grp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be using recursive CTE:

- Divide all rows into numbered partitions grouped by `id` and ordered by `start_date` and `end_date`
- Iterate over them calculating `group_start_date` for each row (rows which have to be merged in final result would have the same `group_start_date`)
- Finally you need to group the CTE by `id` and `group_start_date` taking max `end_date` from each group.

Here is corresponding sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7059b/2

And the SQL, just in case:

```
WITH cteSequencing AS (
  -- Get Values Order
  SELECT *, start_date AS group_start_date,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date, end_date) AS iSequence
  FROM users),

Recursion AS (
  -- Anchor - the first value in groups
  SELECT *
  FROM cteSequencing
  WHERE iSequence = 1
  UNION ALL
  -- Remaining items
  SELECT b.id, b.start_date, b.end_date,
    CASE WHEN a.end_date > b.start_date THEN a.group_start_date 
    ELSE b.start_date
    END
    AS groupStartDate,
    b.iSequence
  FROM Recursion AS a
  INNER JOIN cteSequencing AS b ON a.iSequence + 1 = b.iSequence AND a.id = b.id) 
SELECT id, group_start_date as start_date, MAX(end_date) as end_date FROM Recursion group by id, group_start_date ORDER BY id, group_start_date
```